# Нужна или не нужна запятая?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

*[Мама пришла и на меня рассердилась: «Я же тебя просила не мешать отдыхающим!» И тогда все сказали, что это они сами шумели, чтобы я была подвижная.] **А дядя с усами сказал, что он тут скучал, а сегодня прекрасно провёл время(?) и что пускай всегда детей сюда берут в порядке исключения.***
[**А. Барто. В порядке исключения**](http://rulibs.com/ru_zar/child_verse/barto/4/j34.html)

Я никак не могу понять — почему нет запятой в указанном месте.
(Просмотрела ещё два источника — там тоже отсутствует.)
А как вы считаете, нужна она или нет? Почему?

Answer (score 1):

А дядя с усами **сказал, что** он тут скучал, а сегодня прекрасно провёл время **и что** пускай всегда детей сюда берут в порядке исключения.

СПП с однородными **изъяснительными** придаточными, опорное слово ***сказал***, одиночный союз И, поэтому нет запятой.